# Memory growing in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

My code for custom cell:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ImageView"];
    NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:_imageUrls[indexPath.row]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: nsurl];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ImageView"];
    }

    return cell;
```

And I have custom class VKTableViewCell:

```
   @interface VKTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

    @end
```

Image is about 800x800 (parsed from site).
When I scroll my table, memory is growing (from 20 to 30mb with 100 images load). Why this happening? What I must do in this case? I am using ARC.

Comment: While not related to this issue, probably, you should probably put the call to set the image after the call to create a new cell. (In the case where dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier returned nil.

Comment: Everything you're doing is wrong. You _must_ not use networking synchronously in `cellForRow`. You must return the cell _immediately_. The user is scrolling _now_. Return a cell _now_.

Comment: @matt I know about quality of service and threads something, yet. This is not last version of code. But assuming that it is main thread, is it normal for memory leaks?

Comment: You are downloading the image _every time we see the same cell_ (e.g. scroll up and down and up and down). That is lunacy. _Store the images in the data model_. Everything you're doing is wrong. (I think I said that.)

Comment: @matt thanks, i'll do it

Comment: @matt, How I exactly must use model? Storing a hundreds of images will be painful. Could you give a hint?

Comment: You can let them go again when the row scrolls out of view (expunge them from the model) if memory becomes an issue. But experiment; if they are small, there might be no issue with 100s.

Comment: Look at the explanation of MyDownloader and table view in this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch37.html#_http_requests Notice how I show a placeholder, download in the background, and stop downloading if the image is no longer needed (scrolled out of view)

Comment: @matt Okay, I'll see, thank you.

Comment: @matt I understand my main fault. Such are big images can't be in UITableView, only preview. There isn't sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making Network call on Main Thread that's why it is doing two things at same time

1. Rendering UITableView Cells
2. Making Network call for Images

> Now You have to shift your Network call logic from `Main Thread to BackGround Thread`

```
dispatch_queue_t callerQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.processsmagequeue", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; //Make Network call on BackGround Thread

    dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{
        // Assign Your Image to UIimageView of Cell here on Main Thread
        [cell setNeedsLayout]; // To Refresh Cell
    });
});
```

Also You can use a third Party Api [AFNetWorking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/r4uwx.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
```

**New Solution:**

Lazy load all the images in UITableViewCell for that just make a UIImageView extension like below

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImageFrom(_ link:String, contentMode: UIView.ContentMode) {

        guard let url = URL(string: link) else {
           return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.contentMode = contentMode
                self.image = UIImage(data: data ?? Data())
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Function Call:

```
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")  //set placeholder image first.
cell.imageView.downloadImageFrom(link: dataSource[indexPath.row], contentMode: UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit)  //set your image from link array.
```

Comment: I used your approach. But how to refresh without reloading the cell? When it get loaded it is empty.

Comment: Once you will get imageData then In the next step you have to assign that data to cell.imageView on main Thread. By doing this you don't have to reload cell again

Comment: dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]; 
}). After that images comes only when I click the cell. By default it is empty, but image is loaded.

Comment: Then you have 2 options here 1- place a break point here on this line where you are assigning the data to uiimageView and second is check the background color of your cell and downloading image

Comment: I think that Images are downloading from Network but there is some problem while assigning them

Comment: They are actually good loaded (checked with breakpoints). But they appeared on screen only when alfter cell is clicked.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout there ?

Comment: No, I'm not using AutoLayout.

Comment: Change the background color of imageView so that you know it is appearing there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93103/discussion-between-pavel-and-muhammad-waqas-bhati).